# Converting objects to text that can be reproduced by eval(); anomolies with function object

Tags: javascript

My objective is to translate an object into text form that can be stored using, say, *localStorage*, and subsequently retrieved and converted back to its original object form using eval(). I have written a function called uneval() to do the conversion to text as follows:

```
function uneval(obj){
// Convert object to a string that can be evaluated with eval() to its original
if(obj===null)return 'null';
     if(typeof obj === 'number' || typeof obj === 'boolean')return ''+obj;
if(typeof obj === 'string')return '"'+obj+'"';
if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]')
{   var str = '[', i=0, l=obj.length;
    for(i;i<l;i++)str+= (i==0?'':',') + uneval(obj[i]);
    return str+']';
}
if(typeof obj === 'object')
{   var str='({', i;
    for (i in obj)str+= (2==str.length?'':',') + i + ':' + uneval(obj[i]);
    return str+='})';
}
if(typeof obj === 'function')return '(' + obj.toString() + ')';

return '';}
```

[Edit 1: An object in {} needs parenthese around to be successfully converted using eval()]

[Edit 2: Function code amended to place parentheses around the function code string]

[Edit 3: Changed to a named function for recursion avoiding arguments.callee]

[Edit 4: Handle null]

Note that this function retains nested structure. It works fine (at least in Google Chrome and MS IE8) except when the object, or an item of the object, is a function. I have found a workaround by making an assignment of the function in string form to an unlikely variable, as "_=". That does the job. Without that, I get a syntax error from eval(). Could anyone explain why that is the case, please?

By the way, I can avoid the small chance of a conflict using _ as a variable by calling eval() within a cover function in which _ is localised.

Comment: Side note: `arguments.callee` throws in the strict language, so you should *not* be using it anymore.

Comment: Also `typeof null` returns `'object'`. You should factor that in.

Comment: Also, it's not clear from your code, but `uneval` should be declared beforehand (e.g. `var uneval;`). Otherwise, it becomes an implied global property which is also a violation of the strict language.

Comment: I still have no explanation concerning the rejection of text for a function in eval() without the gratuitous assignment to a variable.

Comment: *"I get a syntax error from eval()"*. Where do you use `eval`? I don't see it in your code?

Comment: It works for me. I've tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE10. http://jsfiddle.net/UqCFp/

Comment: @sime Vidas This is a dialog using Chrome: <br/>
    
    xx=uneval(function(x){return x}) <br>
"_=function (x){return x}" <br>
    eval(xx)<br> 
function (x){return x} <br>
    eval(xx)(5) <br> 
5 <br>
eval("function(x){return x}")  <br> 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (  <br> 
In the last entry/response I omitted the "_=" that I insert in my uneval() function. Without that, I get the syntax error.

Comment: @sime Vidas: Sorry, I'm having a problem with the formating (newbie here)

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
var func = eval('function () {}');
```

`eval` parses the string as a function *declaration*, not a function *expression*, and since function declarations cannot be anonymous, a syntax error is thrown. In order to ensure that your string is parsed as a function expression, instead of a declaration, just add parens at the beginning, and end of the string. These parents will be parsed as the [grouping operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.6). The contents of the grouping operator are then parsed as an expression; in this case, a function expression.

```
var func = eval('(function () {})'); // doesn't throw
```

So, in your `uneval` function, do this:

```
if ( typeof obj === 'function' ) return '(' + obj.toString() + ')';
```

Comment: @crosseyed I've brushed up my knowledge on eval, so it's a win-win `:-)`